# MySQL Load Data Infil - Convert loaded date into number

Tags: mysql, function

I am trying to do a LOAD DATE INFILE in mysql, and am trying to convert data from one of the loaded columns into a number based on a table I have set up in the database already. Below is what my query looks like currently.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'path\\Grand Export.csv'

INTO TABLE student

FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'

LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'

IGNORE 1 ROWS
(fameid, @ssn, @sname, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy,
@dummy, @dummy, address, city, state, @dummy, zip, @dummy, 
@dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy,
@dummy, @dummy, @dob, @gender, @ethnicity, @dummy, @dummy)

SET

ssn = concat(LEFT(@ssn,3),MID(@ssn,5,2),RIGHT(@ssn,4)),
fname = substring_index(trim(both """" FROM @sname),',',1),
lname = substring_index(TRIM(BOTH """" FROM @sname),',',-1),
gender = LEFT(@gender,1),
dob = date_format(str_to_date(@dob,'%m/%d/%Y'),'%Y-%m-%d'),
ethid = CALL getethid(@ethnicity);
```

The problem is that the getethid function isn't working. The code for it looks like this:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `getethid`(eth VARCHAR(40))
RETURNS INT
BEGIN

DECLARE @valethid INT;

SELECT ethid FROM fameEth WHERE ethnicity = eth
INTO @valethid;

RETURN @valethid;

END
```

Every time I try to run this it tells me that there is a syntax error. What am I doing wrong here?

UPDATE: I adjusted the code for both an am now encountering a new problem:

Load data code below:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\ProgramData\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.7\\Uploads\\Grand Export.csv'
INTO TABLE student

FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS

(fameid, @ssn, @sname, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, address, city,
state, @dummy, zip, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy,
@dummy, @dummy, @dob, @gender, @ethnicity)

SET
ssn = concat(LEFT(@ssn,3),MID(@ssn,5,2),RIGHT(@ssn,4)),
fname = substring_index(trim(both """" FROM @sname),',',1),
lname = substring_index(TRIM(BOTH """" FROM @sname),',',-1),
gender = LEFT(@gender,1),
dob = date_format(str_to_date(@dob,'%m/%d/%Y'),'%Y-%m-%d'),
ethid = getethid(@ethnicity);
```

Function code here:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `getethid`(eth VARCHAR(40))
RETURNS int(11)
BEGIN

SELECT ethid FROM ethnicity WHERE ethnicity = eth
INTO @valueid;

RETURN @valueid;
END
```

The LOAD DATA query now executes, but the ethid value is not being correctly populated. It is not recognizing certain types of data and consequently is defauling to the previous data value in later rows.

Comment: Format your post in a nice way so that it appears good for your readers.

Answer (score 0):

Are you supposed to use "CALL" when invoking a function?  I thought that was only for stored procedures.  Try removing the word CALL, leaving "ethid = getethid(@ethnicity)".

[Create Procedure or Function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html)

Comment: Unfortunately I need to get the function syntax fixed before I can sent it to the LOAD DATA INLINE. Any idea of what might be wrong with the function?

Comment: Add LIMIT 1 to the SELECT statement inside your function.  I would need to know more about the problem - "not recognizing certain types of data".  Perhaps an example of a call that succeeds and one that fails.  Any warnings or errors returned would also be helpful.

Be sure to test the function in isolation using a SELECT statement instead of your LOAD DATA.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I got it working. Here was the final code:

Create Function as follows:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `getethid`(IN eth VARCHAR(40), OUT newid INT)
BEGIN

SELECT ethid FROM fameEth WHERE ethnicity = eth;

END
```

(This is using the MySQL workbench mind you)

Upload code as follows:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\ProgramData\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.7\\Uploads\\Grand Export.csv'
INTO TABLE student
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS
(fameid, @ssn, @sname, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, address, city,
state, @dummy, zip, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy,
@dummy, @dummy, @dob, @gender, @ethnicity, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy)

SET ssn = concat(LEFT(@ssn,3),MID(@ssn,5,2),RIGHT(@ssn,4)),
fname = substring_index(trim(both """" FROM @sname),',',1),
lname = substring_index(TRIM(BOTH """" FROM @sname),',',-1),
gender = LEFT(@gender,1),
dob = date_format(str_to_date(@dob,'%m/%d/%Y'),'%Y-%m-%d'),
ethid = getethid(@ethnicity);
```

The last issue I was encountering was due to a missing value in my reference table. Once I updated it the getethid() function worked perfectly.

Thanks to everyone for all of your help!